# Connecting Android to Windows 7 fails

Tags: windows, htc-wildfire

My Windows 7 doesn't recognize my android phone. HTC Wildfire S

Are there any updates of drivers that I need?

If I use VMWare it works properly here's what it showed in VMWare.

[image]

**But here's what happens in device manager on my windows 7 on the same computer**

[image]

Please help!! I've installed HTC Sync and tried connecting, my phone and the PC fails to connect. Help!!!

Comment: Have you choosen that windows will look online for drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all answers, but my case was a very unusual case. I tried everything but It didn't work. I reinstalled windows. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I have problems with installing an Android device's drivers, I install [PDANet](http://junefabrics.com/android/).

PDANet is a desktop tethering app, but that isn't why I install it.  PDANet comes bundled with phone drivers for all of the major phone manufacturers.  Once you have installed the drivers, you can then uninstall PDANet (and it will keep the drivers).

Comment: PDANet is not even passing the installation of the Android Driver. It cannot even find my phone.

Comment: @Mob Not sure what else to suggest, PDANet has always fixed driver issues for me.  Did you try uninstalling what is installed already in the device manager first, then install PDANet (and drivers), then plug in phone?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try modifying the Android SDK driver's .inf file to allow the drivers to be used for your device.  I have instructions in another answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/16195/1465).