# Galaxy Tab 10.1 on windows xp 64bit

Tags: usb, adb, samsung-galaxy-tab, windows, usb-drivers

I've installed samsung drivers from mobile v1.4.103.0 on windows xp64 from the latest kies package (I've only installed usb drivers).

I see `Android ADB interface` in windows devices but adb still says `no devices`, I've tried by adding the vendor id to `adb_usb.ini` without success.

Perhaps using linux on vmware and passing the usb device works fine without adding the vendor id.

Suggestions?

No luck also with drivers 1.3.1500.0

Comment: Do you have USB Debugging enabled?

Comment: yes, using linux on vmware it works fine, I also have an acer liquid mini that works with adb on this windows

Comment: OK. You mention `adb_usb.ini`, do you mean `android_winusb.inf`?  [This](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/16195/1465) might help. Make sure you update the driver via Device Manager after editing the .inf file, of course.

Comment: google usb drivers are needed if the vendor does not supplies drivers, same tablet works with adb on a windows 7 32bit so it should be something related to the os (somehow)

Comment: winxp 32bit works, why -1?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I answer myself:

after installing samsung drivers you need to find oem??.inf file that contains `ssudserd.inf`
comment out all references to wdf stuff version 1.7 and decomment the ones referring 1.9