# Ramos W16 Android Usb driver

Tags: rooting

Have an issue with my Ramos W16. Upgraded to the last firmware. Now I want to root device, but can't install drivers. Here is hardware Id's USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E22&REV_0231 USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E22

OS: Windows 7 x64. In Device management tablet is visible as USB Composite Device. I've tried a bunch of different drivers, but they don't work. Somebody help me! Tried USBDeview - deleted all drivers.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/16071/1465)?

Comment: if I disable USB debugging drivers automatically installing in Windows 7 x64. But if enable USB debugging device visible as usb composite device and any manipulations with andoid_winusb.inf can't help. Also if I plug in device with turned off usb debugging hw id is USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E21, but when plug ing with usb debugging turned on hw id is USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E22.

Comment: You should add entries for both.