# How to install fastboot drivers?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, boot, bootloader

I have a cheap clone android (benss b3) that I managed to connect to win 7 by editing the .inf file in usb drivers. Now I want to load different ROMs via fastboot. However, when I boot to fastboot mode (?, power on with back + power button pressed), I get a new device in windows  device manager. I can't get the usb drivers working and no devices appear with fastboot.

How can I get the fastboot to detect my device?

Comment: How did you edit the .inf file?  It should be the same process just with the new values.

Comment: I would like to get more help with the inf file also. I just copy-pasted the usb-hardware-id (usb/rev_*&mid_*&...) to values of %composite...% and %single...%. And also I put the hardware-name to the end of the list with google, nexus, ... But this does not work for fastboot mode. The id and the name are slightly different. I am not now on windows, but I will check the exact values soon. The procedure should work like this, right?

Comment: Also I am not sure if its fastboot mode that I booted into. How can I verify that it is? How should a fastboot mode be seen in device manager? Can it be that it is just showing the "disks". I could swear that in some point I saw 2 new android drives in device manager.

Comment: Your device should say "fastboot" or "bootloader" or have a picture of a yellow triangle.  You should also be able to get there by connecting your (normally booted up) device to the PC and running `adb reboot bootloader`.  And yes, the .inf editing should be exactly like that; see http://android.stackexchange.com/a/16195/1465