# How does the safe/fastboot/recovery mode differ from the normal as seen from windows pc?

Tags: windows, usb-connection-mode, fastboot, recovery-mode

This is a related question to:

[How to install fastboot drivers?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23122/how-to-install-fastboot-drivers)

I have trouble using the command line fastboot program. I think that I don't have the correct drivers installed. How can I verify this? What there should be on device manager -> driver details when you are in fastboot mode?

What is the correct term for this mode?

Comment: You may check your phone manufacturer web site for a windows drivers download.

Comment: This might vary by device. If I'm remembering right, a Kindle Fire in fastboot mode (without proper drivers installed) will simply be listed in the device manager as "Kindle", or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The Motorola USB drivers can be found at http://developer.motorola.com/tools/resources/

On Motorola devices, it enumerates as "Mot Single ADB Interface"