# ADB pull fails to pull folder that exists

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, adb

I have a folder I am trying to pull from my G3. Specifically `system/etc/wifi/`

When I pull that specific folder in adb it gives me an error

`remote object 'system/etc/wifi' does not exist`

But yet I can pull the entire etc and it copes all files and folders EXCEPT wifi.

The permission on the folder are `rwxr-xr-x` just like the rest of them.

Here is the output to prove that wifi is a folder and that I can pull from etc

```
C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop>adb shell
shell@g3:/ $ su
root@g3:/ # cd system/etc
root@g3:/system/etc # ls
More files/folders..
ppp
..
wifi
More files/folders..
root@g3:/system/etc # exit
shell@g3:/ $ exit

C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop>adb pull system/etc/ppp
pull: building file list...
pull: system/etc/ppp/ip-up-vpn -> ./ip-up-vpn
1 file pulled. 0 files skipped.
307 KB/s (5344 bytes in 0.016s)

C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop>adb pull system/etc/wifi
remote object 'system/etc/wifi' does not exist
```

Output of `ls -l` on system/etc/

`drwxr-xr-x root     root              2016-03-13 18:32 wifi`

I can pull ppp just fine, but not wifi

**Edit**

Trying to move the folder to sdcard then pulling it

adb shell su -c "cp -R /system/etc/wifi /sdcard

adb pull /sdcard/wifi

```
C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop>adb pull /system/etc/wifi
remote object '/system/etc/wifi' does not exist

C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop>adb shell su -c "cp -R /system/etc/wifi /sdcard
cp: /sdcard: File exists

C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop>adb pull sdcard/wifi
remote object 'sdcard/wifi' does not exist
```

Why is this? and how can I pull this folder off.  I have granted root permissions to `adb`.

Comment: When you try to pull etc alone, do you see any error when it attempts to download wifi directory?

Comment: @Firelord it skipped wifi, no mention of it at all

Comment: I'm going to boot into TWRP and then go into adb to see if the running wifi process is causing this

Comment: `cp: /sdcard: File exists` Now that's odd.  Seems like it is treating directories as files?  It succeeds on my device.  You're missing a trailing quote on that command, maybe try to double check, but it succeeds on my device even without it so :/

Comment: Sadly not, this is extremely strange.  Let us know how it works in TWRP.

Comment: You might need an extra driver for Recovery mode.  You could try [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/16195/1465) or Izzy's answer there if the G3 drivers don't include it.

Comment: Pulling the folder from TWRP recovery worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to post this answer for future reference in case anyone experiences this problem. I was unable to pull the folder `system/etc/wifi/` using adb with root privileges until I booted into recovery.

I was using TWRP 3.0.0-0 and I was then able to access adb in TWRP and then pull the folder in question. I am unsure of why the folder was not pullable in the first place but pulling it from recovery works.

Commands **successfully** used in recovery

`adb pull system/etc/wifi`